# JS - Apply limit on array of object

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i have a simple array of object in js

```
const users = [
   {categories: 'FRENCH', user: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}, 
   {categories: 'BELGIUM', user: [{id: 5}, {id: 3}, {id:4}]},
   {categories: 'USA', user: [{id: 12}, {id: 13}, {id:15}]}  
]
```

I want to limit this array depending on user size
So for example if i want `only 3 user` a function name `limitTo(users, 3)` should return :

```
const only3users = [
   {categories: 'FRENCH', user: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}, 
   {categories: 'BELGIUM', user: [{id: 5}]}, 
]
```

What's the best algorithm to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fairly simple recursive version would look like this:

```js
const limitTo = ([{user, ...rest} = {}, ...xs], n) =>
  user 
    ? user .length >= n 
      ? [{... rest, user: user .slice (0, n)}]
      : [{... rest, user}, ... limitTo (xs, n - user .length)]
    : []

const users = [{categories: 'FRENCH', user: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}, {categories: 'BELGIUM', user: [{id: 5}, {id: 3}, {id:4}]}, {categories: 'USA', user: [{id: 12}, {id: 13}, {id:15}]}];

[3, 5, 7, 20] .forEach (n => console .log (`Count ${n}:`, limitTo (users, n)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If we have no more root objects, then `user` will be `undefined` and so we return an empty array.  Otherwise, we compare the number of `user`s in the object.  If it's greater than or equal to the target, `n`, we return an object with a `user` array containing the first `n` pieces.  Otherwise we include the current object as well as the recursive results for the remaining objects and a target reduced by the number of users in the current object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way but working :

```
const users = [
  {categories: 'FRENCH', user: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}, 
  {categories: 'BELGIUM', user: [{id: 5}, {id: 3}, {id:4}]},
  {categories: 'USA', user: [{id: 12}, {id: 13}, {id:15}]}  
]

function limitTo(arr, n) {
  let stack = []
  const res = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let item = arr[i]
    if (stack.length === n) return res
    if (item.user.length < n - stack.length) {
      res.push(item)
      stack = [...stack, ...item.user]
    } else {
      const rest = n - stack.length
      const users = item.user.splice(0, rest)
      item = { ...item, user: users }
      res.push(item)
      stack = [...stack, ...users]
    }
  }

  return res
}

limitTo(users, 3)
```

We use a stack array that stores the users when that we decide to add to our response. We compare the users length for each object of the array with the N number of users you want minus the stack length (already added users).
If our response can deal with all the users, we add them all. Else, we splice the user array by the proper number.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Two comments: First, you are not using the `stack` variable as an actual stack.  All you're doing is adding elements and testing it's length.  You could do just as well with a `count` variable that you simply add to.  Second, although it works, `splice` is probably the wrong method mere, as it mutates the input.  You would get the same behavior with `slice`, without mutating the original.